# Connecting Leaflet Component Using a Proxy

Tags: java, dictionary, proxy

I am supporting a project in Ignition Perspective (V 8.1.24) for a customer SCADA platform. Due to firewall rules and local regulations, we do not have internet access and therefore cannot use the Leaflet map feature. The customers' IT department gave us a proxy that we can use for internet access. Is there a way to point just the Leaflet map component to that proxy?

We have searched through online resources and the Ignition manual for solutions

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.